# Searching for OU in AD using powershell

Tags: active-directory, powershell-4.0

The variable $GetOU is suppose to ask the user to enter a number to search in AD

But, if I put $GetOU, it gives an error message.  How would I put the value of $GetOU in the Get-ADOrganizationalUnit

```
$GetOU = Read-Host "Please enter branch number to search AD OU "

Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter 'Name -like "*7402*"' | Select-Object DistinguishedName, Name
```

Basically, where it says 7402, I want it to get the value of $GetOU

Also, what does the ** before and after 7402 mean?

The script finds 7402 OU in AD, but I want the user to be able to enter the number.

Comment: Please ignore this edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In order to use the value of `$GetOU`, you need to perform variable expansion inside a string. Since single-quoted strings do not expand variables, you can use a double-quoted string, like this:

   ```
   Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -like `"*$GetOU*`"" | Select-Object DistinguishedName, Name
   ```

   Notice that I had to put the ` character before the ", so PowerShell won't terminate the string.
2. The `*` is used as a wildcard, to match anything before and after the `$GetOU`.